# What's the difference between "ones", "the ones", "those", "one", "the one", "that"?

Tags: pronouns, determiners

I am wondering what the difference is between "ones", "the ones", "one", the one", "those", and "that"?

Take a noun for example. Some people say a dog=one, dogs=ones, the dog=the one=that, and the dogs=the ones=those. It's a rule of thumb, but what I found was that this is not always correct. There are exceptions.

For example, in the case of "A chair made of wood is as good as one made of leather", this sentence is equal to "A chair made of wood is as good as a chair made of leather". The two sentences are different from "A chair made of wood is as good as that made of leather." or "A chair made of wood is as good as the one made of leather.", because they are not talking about specific ones, the determiner "the" and the pronouns that represent "specific ones", such as "that", are not needed here.

However, when it comes to plural nouns, there are exceptions.

For example,

Chairs made of wood are as good as ones made of leather=Chairs made of wood are as good as those made of leather.

Some people may argue that "those" refer to "specific ones", but in this case, it somehow refers to all of the chairs made of leather in general.

However, if we change it to

Chairs made of wood are as good as the ones made of leather.

Chairs made of wood are as good as the chairs made of leather

The meanings are different. It seems that "those" is sometimes equal to "ones", especially when we compare things, while "one" is never equal to "that"

What do you think about it?

All opinions and advice are welcome.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

My main objection to OP's reasoning is that "ones" will not work alone to express generic plural (INCORRECT: *Chairs made of wood are as good as **ones** made of leather) **unless it is premodified**:

- Chairs made of wood (or wooden chairs) are as good as **leather ones**. (*ones made of leather* is not good language)

I agree that "one" is indefinite in the singular while "the one" and "that" are definite in the singular.

- *A chair made of wood is as good as **one** made of leather.* (indefinite, singular)
- *This chair made of wood is as good as **that (one)** made of leather.* (definite, singular)
- *The chair made of wood is as good as **the one** made of leather.* (definite, singular)

"the ones" and "those" can be indefinite or definite depending on the context:

- *Chairs made of wood are as good as **those** made of leather.* (indefinite, plural)
- *These chairs made of wood are as good as **those** made of leather.* (definite, plural)
- *Chairs made of wood are as good as **the ones** made of leather.* (indefinite, plural)
- *The chairs made of wood are as good as **the ones** made of leather.* (definite, plural)

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I thought! We use plural nouns to mean something specific all the time: Cars made in China are worse than those (the ones) made in Korea. Here, it can be argued that Cars made in China are a specific group of things!

Comment: My claim is that the plural can be specific or not, that is, definite or indefinite (see my examples with *those* and *the ones*).

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. It's interesting to find someone who knows what I mean here. Usually people insist that "those" are only equal to definite things because it's the plural form of that. I thought I was the only one who had ever noticed it and raised a question.

Answer (score 1):

I find your examples

```
    *Chairs made of wood are as good as the chairs made of leather.  
    *Chairs made of wood are as good as the ones made of leather.
```

to be not fully grammatical, though the example is okay with "those" in place of "the ones/chairs".  (Perhaps we should distinguish between "ones" as a plural indefinite noun in "the ones" and as a pronoun (so called) which stands for an entire indefinite NP.)

Comment: Which part of it do you think is not grammatical? Would you please kindly point it out so that we can discuss?

Comment: @GregLee What IS ungrammatical in my opinion is *Chairs made of wood are as good as **ones** made of leather.*

Comment: @Gustavson, Well, your example sounds okay, to me.

Comment: @GregLee Please clarify, which example? The one containing "as good as ones made of leather"?

Comment: @ChienTeLu, I said what I meant.  The two example sentences that I cited are not fullly grammatical, in my opinion.

Comment: @Gustavson, I refer to the sentence you cited in your comment, "Chairs made of wood are as good as ones made of leather."  I find that grammatical.

Comment: @GregLee Well, usually ungrammatical means that it doesn't follow the general rules of grammar, so we can usually find mistakes in ungrammatical sentences. Not all grammatical sentences are right, and not all ungrammatical sentences are wrong, either. If I write "You is beautiful", this is both wrong and ungrammatical. I don't see anything wrong in the two sentences you mentioned.

Comment: @ChienTeLu, Actually, "ungrammatical" is used ambiguously. Sometimes it means not generated by the rules of some known, agreed on grammar.  Commonly, though, it means not accepted by native speakers as part of the language.  So there is usually some confusion about this.  I was just now using "ungrammatical" to mean "not acceptable".  (And then, native speakers often disagree.)

Comment: @ChienTeLu I answered to the best of my knowledge, and "as good as ones..." does not sound right to me. However, I'm a teacher but not a native speaker of English, so Greg might be right. I will submit to the authority of educated native speakers, and he seems to be one. I'd like to hear other native speakers' opinions, though.

Comment: @Gustavson It's totally okay. I am not a native speaker either, and I believe your experience is valuable enough!

Comment: @GregLee I know what you mean now. So what do you think about using "those" to refer to indefinite things? Do you think whether it's totally acceptable and understandable or just wrong?

Comment: @Gustavson, I'm not trying to pull rank on you.  As I noted, native speakers of English often disagree in their judgments.  It is quite possible other English speakers will agree with you.  There might be no one right answer.  It can be a confusing world.

Comment: @GregLee Quite the contrary, you are very respectful (unlike some other people here). I really meant what I said and I will always consider the possibility of being wrong if educated native speakers like you have a different opinion.

Comment: @ChienTeLu, As I said, I find "those" alone to be okay when the first subject is indefinite "chairs".  (Perhaps it is to be taken as short for *"those ones".)